# Fixing go: inconsistent vendoring in C:\Go\src

Tags: go, web-applications

I recently started learning Go programming language for Web and now I can't build my project. I'm getting "inconsistent vendoring". I checked github and the library is missing i.e. (Actually the library is still there but with no v0.1.0)
[vscode error type on build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPGxS.png)

Comment: Take a look at this Github issue: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/34657

Answer (score 37):

Run the following before go build

```sh
go mod tidy
go mod vendor
```

Comment: As a side note, the `go mod tidy` will delete files in your environment that go is expected to rebuild.

Comment: Should I run `go mod init` before them?

Answer (score 4):

This problem can also occur if you `vendor/modules.txt` file is missing. This happened in a project that gitignored `*.txt` and the solution was simply to commit this file and then follow what @amit-basuri wrote in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58512507/1260548).

Answer (score 1):

On windows:

Initially, I had my packages in `C\:Go\src`. It turns out that, go creates other directories in `C:\Users\USERNAME\go\src\`. I therefore moved my (personal) packages into the `C:\Users\USERNAME\go\src\` folder and those from github into the `C:\Users\USERNAME\go\src\github.com` folder.
Everything started working again.

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same problem recently, all I had to do was remove the `go.mod` and `go.sum` files I created in my `C:User\go\src` directory.

I guess this happens because `go.mod` is meant to be used outside your working directory and since these files are located in the source directory, you don't need